# How can you rename all the fields within a JSON array using Laravel that match X?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

My array looks like this:

```
array:145 [▼
  144 => array:2 [▼
    0 => 1559739600000
    1 => 39103.5828125
  ]
  143 => array:2 [▼
    0 => 1559739000000
    1 => 39102.619270833
  ]
  142 => array:2 [▼
    0 => 1559738400000
    1 => 39101.740234375
  ]
...
```

I need to change the 0s to time and 1s to data, so I can work with them within Laravel.  If I try to reference them within Laravel like $0 I get T_Variable errors because of the rules that variables should not start with numbers. So I'm in a bind. So it ends up looking something like this:

```
array:145 [▼
  144 => array:2 [▼
    time => 1559739600000
    data => 39103.5828125
  ]
  143 => array:2 [▼
    time => 1559739000000
    data => 39102.619270833
  ]
  142 => array:2 [▼
    time => 1559738400000
    data => 39101.740234375
  ]
...
```

Comment: Why do you set your variable to `$0`? How are you using the data? You can set the variable name to anything you want, doesn't have to be exactly like the `key`...

Comment: @ChinLeung I did not set it, the API outputs it in that fashion. I have no controll over the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this using Laravel Collection.

```
$result = collect($array)->map(function ($item) {
    return [
        'time' => $item[0],
        'data' => $item[1],
    ];
})->all();
```

I find this approach quite common in the Laravel community. For more info, pls check: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections

Comment: I ended up using something similar that I crafted. Thanks.